# Core Data. Filter by date

Tags: swift, core-data

I have a .xcdatamodel in Core Data with the Entity Content and the Attributes dateCreated Type Date and text1 Type String.

```
//CREATE
   func createData() {
       guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
       let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
       let contentEntity = NSEntityDescription.entity(forEntityName: "Content", in: managedContext)!

       let content = NSManagedObject(entity: contentEntity, insertInto: managedContext)
       content.setValue(Date(), forKey: "dateCreated")
       content.setValue("someText", forKey: "text1")

       do {
           try managedContext.save()
       } catch let error as NSError {
           print("Could not save. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
       }
    }

//READ
    func readData() {
           guard let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate else { return }
           let managedContext = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
           let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Content")
           fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "text1 = %@", "some text")

           do {
               let result = try managedContext.fetch(fetchRequest)

               for data in result as! [NSManagedObject] {
                   print(data.value(forKey: "dateCreated") as! Date)
                   print(data.value(forKey: "text1") as! String)
               }
           } catch {
               print("Failed")
           }
       }
```

if I print dateCreated, it gives: 2020-03-12 10:20:42 +0000
My question is: how can I read and filter by date? Only date, not time. For instance 2020-03-12 or any other date without time:

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "dateCreated = %@", ?????)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [CoreData conditionally fetching on NSDate using NSPredicate (swift)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31397408/coredata-conditionally-fetching-on-nsdate-using-nspredicate-swift)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57205589/1187415

Comment: Thank you both, those references are useful. But my question is different and still, with that information, I cannot solve the problem

Comment: If it is of type `Date` then `dateCreated` is not stored in "2020-03-12 10:20:42 +0000" format, even if that's the format that is displayed when you print it.  As the links provided by @MartinR and @mag_xbc show, to filter items on a given DAY, regardless of time, you need to select items where dateCreated falls after midnight on the day in question and before midnight of the day after.  That's what those answers achieve.

Answer (score 0):

In **CreateData()**  you're storing the date by using **Date()**. So that it will be stored in you're database with the format **yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss ZZZZ**. That's why it prints this **2020-03-12 10:20:42 +0000**

Change from

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "text1 = %@", "some text")
```

to

```
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "dateCreated = %@", Date())
```

if you using this predicate instead of text1, the core data will give you result with Date and it'll be difficult to filter if there is time. So you have to insert the date by changing its format to **yyyy-MM-dd**

You can change the current date format by using **DateFormatter()**.

```
//Needed date format
let dateFormat = DateFormatter()
dateFormat.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd"
let formattedDate = dateFormat.string(from: Date())
```

So try by inserting the Date() by changing its format

```
//in CreateData()
content.setValue(formattedDate, forKey: "dateCreated")

//in ReadData()
fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "dateCreated = %@", formattedDate)
```

Comment: I understand you are converting the date-time to date. But how to make the readData request and filter to the database?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't get you. Are trying to fetch the datas by filtering the date?

Comment: `let datePredicate = NSPredicate(format: "dateCreated = %@", currentDate)` before doing this you have to check the format used to store in core data. Because the format of currentDate and dateCreated must be same.

Comment: I tried to explain it in another way. I updated my question

Comment: I've updated the answer, again I'm saying the format of date in predicate and core data must be same

Comment: The first option does not work: fetchRequest.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "dateCreated = %@", Date())

Comment: The second options is a possible solution but only with Attribute Type String. It means that you have to change the xcdatamodeld Attribute Type from Date to String. If you do that you have to make a new Project or make a migration that is more complicated.